# Is there a 2-D "where" in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

This might seem an odd question, but it boils down to quite a simple operation that I can't find a numpy equivalent for. I've looked at `np.where` as well as many other operations but can't find anything that does this:

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
c = np.array([i<b for i in a])
```

The output is a 2-D array (3,4), of booleans comparing each value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to get `c` without loop, try this

```
# make "a" a column vector
# > broadcasts to produce a len(a) x len(b) array
c = b > a[:, None]
c
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the approach in the other answer to get the values of `a` and `b`. Given a mask of

```
c = b > a[:, None]
```

You can extract the indices for each dimension using `np.where` or `np.nonzero`:

```
row, col = np.nonzero(c)
```

And use the indices to get the corresponding values:

```
ag = a[row]
bg = b[col]
```

Elements of `a` and `b` may be repeated in the result.